# Heroku App Failing to Deploy on Rails Deployment, whats going wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, heroku, deployment

Can anyone help me on this? My app keeps falling over when I deploy to Heroku. I'm not entirely sure what's going on.

I'm not that great at reading error message logs, and this is one of my first apps I've deployed. I'm happy to provide my gem file listing as well as maybe it's to do with these? Or some form of config in my routes? Or my DB?

Just let me know what's needed for debugging.

````
luke@luke-MS-7C91:~/newnewassignment/freelancer_assignment$ heroku logs
2022-06-19T11:36:41.179550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2022-06-19T11:36:43.883502+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2022-06-19T11:36:43.883516+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.3 application starting in production
2022-06-19T11:36:43.883516+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2022-06-19T11:36:45.214698+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2022-06-19T11:36:45.214735+00:00 app[web.1]: * Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Birdie's Version")
2022-06-19T11:36:45.214735+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Min threads: 5
2022-06-19T11:36:45.214735+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Max threads: 5
2022-06-19T11:36:45.214736+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Environment: production
2022-06-19T11:36:45.214736+00:00 app[web.1]: *          PID: 4
2022-06-19T11:36:45.214958+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:41431
2022-06-19T11:36:45.220478+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2022-06-19T11:36:45.467856+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-06-19T11:36:46.502654+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:36:46.502567 #4]  INFO -- : [4b7d4b19-447d-4995-b2cd-465e8b2c3460] Started GET "/" for 86.6.238.212 at 2022-06-19 11:36:46 +0000
2022-06-19T11:36:46.504201+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:36:46.504148 #4]  INFO -- : [4b7d4b19-447d-4995-b2cd-465e8b2c3460] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2022-06-19T11:36:47.819972+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:36:47.819885 #4]  INFO -- : [4b7d4b19-447d-4995-b2cd-465e8b2c3460] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1316ms (ActiveRecord: 1245.3ms | Allocations: 4713)
2022-06-19T11:36:47.820510+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-19T11:36:47.820475 #4] FATAL -- : [4b7d4b19-447d-4995-b2cd-465e8b2c3460]
2022-06-19T11:36:47.820512+00:00 app[web.1]: [4b7d4b19-447d-4995-b2cd-465e8b2c3460] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "freelancers" does not exist
2022-06-19T11:36:47.820512+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 9:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"freelancers"'::regclass
2022-06-19T11:36:47.820513+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-19T11:36:47.820513+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2022-06-19T11:36:47.820514+00:00 app[web.1]: [4b7d4b19-447d-4995-b2cd-465e8b2c3460]
2022-06-19T11:36:47.820514+00:00 app[web.1]: [4b7d4b19-447d-4995-b2cd-465e8b2c3460] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2022-06-19T11:36:47.821959+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=freelancers-applc.herokuapp.com request_id=4b7d4b19-447d-4995-b2cd-465e8b2c3460 fwd="86.6.238.212" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1325ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2022-06-19T11:36:48.010099+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=freelancers-applc.herokuapp.com request_id=b1ceb926-a3b0-4b85-9fbf-62dbd0315434 fwd="86.6.238.212" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2022-06-19T11:37:19.971920+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:37:19.971848 #4]  INFO -- : [f1b6578b-f5bf-4529-b396-b93eff1d46fa] Started GET "/" for 86.6.238.212 at 2022-06-19 11:37:19 +0000
2022-06-19T11:37:19.972700+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:37:19.972643 #4]  INFO -- : [f1b6578b-f5bf-4529-b396-b93eff1d46fa] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2022-06-19T11:37:19.979592+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:37:19.979530 #4]  INFO -- : [f1b6578b-f5bf-4529-b396-b93eff1d46fa] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms | Allocations: 257)
2022-06-19T11:37:19.980043+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-19T11:37:19.980016 #4] FATAL -- : [f1b6578b-f5bf-4529-b396-b93eff1d46fa]
2022-06-19T11:37:19.980043+00:00 app[web.1]: [f1b6578b-f5bf-4529-b396-b93eff1d46fa] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "freelancers" does not exist
2022-06-19T11:37:19.980044+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 9:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"freelancers"'::regclass
2022-06-19T11:37:19.980044+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-19T11:37:19.980044+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2022-06-19T11:37:19.980045+00:00 app[web.1]: [f1b6578b-f5bf-4529-b396-b93eff1d46fa]
2022-06-19T11:37:19.980045+00:00 app[web.1]: [f1b6578b-f5bf-4529-b396-b93eff1d46fa] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2022-06-19T11:37:19.980756+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=freelancers-applc.herokuapp.com request_id=f1b6578b-f5bf-4529-b396-b93eff1d46fa fwd="86.6.238.212" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2022-06-19T11:38:03.688551+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:38:03.688475 #4]  INFO -- : [1620c46f-edc7-4a32-b1b7-acf1e42734aa] Started GET "/" for 86.6.238.212 at 2022-06-19 11:38:03 +0000
2022-06-19T11:38:03.689189+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:38:03.689143 #4]  INFO -- : [1620c46f-edc7-4a32-b1b7-acf1e42734aa] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2022-06-19T11:38:03.694677+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:38:03.694607 #4]  INFO -- : [1620c46f-edc7-4a32-b1b7-acf1e42734aa] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms | Allocations: 230)
2022-06-19T11:38:03.695139+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-19T11:38:03.695107 #4] FATAL -- : [1620c46f-edc7-4a32-b1b7-acf1e42734aa]
2022-06-19T11:38:03.695140+00:00 app[web.1]: [1620c46f-edc7-4a32-b1b7-acf1e42734aa] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "freelancers" does not exist
2022-06-19T11:38:03.695141+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 9:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"freelancers"'::regclass
2022-06-19T11:38:03.695142+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-19T11:38:03.695143+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2022-06-19T11:38:03.695144+00:00 app[web.1]: [1620c46f-edc7-4a32-b1b7-acf1e42734aa]
2022-06-19T11:38:03.695144+00:00 app[web.1]: [1620c46f-edc7-4a32-b1b7-acf1e42734aa] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2022-06-19T11:38:03.695855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=freelancers-applc.herokuapp.com request_id=1620c46f-edc7-4a32-b1b7-acf1e42734aa fwd="86.6.238.212" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2022-06-19T11:38:04.597291+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:38:04.597201 #4]  INFO -- : [dc5a8846-8045-402a-a8d9-cdf7bcbbdcaa] Started GET "/" for 86.6.238.212 at 2022-06-19 11:38:04 +0000
2022-06-19T11:38:04.598144+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:38:04.598089 #4]  INFO -- : [dc5a8846-8045-402a-a8d9-cdf7bcbbdcaa] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2022-06-19T11:38:04.602390+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:38:04.602296 #4]  INFO -- : [dc5a8846-8045-402a-a8d9-cdf7bcbbdcaa] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms | Allocations: 240)
2022-06-19T11:38:04.602855+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-19T11:38:04.602826 #4] FATAL -- : [dc5a8846-8045-402a-a8d9-cdf7bcbbdcaa]
2022-06-19T11:38:04.602858+00:00 app[web.1]: [dc5a8846-8045-402a-a8d9-cdf7bcbbdcaa] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "freelancers" does not exist
2022-06-19T11:38:04.602859+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 9:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"freelancers"'::regclass
2022-06-19T11:38:04.602859+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-19T11:38:04.602860+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2022-06-19T11:38:04.602861+00:00 app[web.1]: [dc5a8846-8045-402a-a8d9-cdf7bcbbdcaa]
2022-06-19T11:38:04.602861+00:00 app[web.1]: [dc5a8846-8045-402a-a8d9-cdf7bcbbdcaa] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2022-06-19T11:38:04.603558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=freelancers-applc.herokuapp.com request_id=dc5a8846-8045-402a-a8d9-cdf7bcbbdcaa fwd="86.6.238.212" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2022-06-19T11:39:09.889273+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:39:09.889191 #4]  INFO -- : [56ddbc7b-7392-4755-9613-c4e2d53b61f3] Started GET "/" for 86.6.238.212 at 2022-06-19 11:39:09 +0000
2022-06-19T11:39:09.890103+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:39:09.890046 #4]  INFO -- : [56ddbc7b-7392-4755-9613-c4e2d53b61f3] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2022-06-19T11:39:09.894212+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-19T11:39:09.894141 #4]  INFO -- : [56ddbc7b-7392-4755-9613-c4e2d53b61f3] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 240)
2022-06-19T11:39:09.895113+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-19T11:39:09.895056 #4] FATAL -- : [56ddbc7b-7392-4755-9613-c4e2d53b61f3]
2022-06-19T11:39:09.895115+00:00 app[web.1]: [56ddbc7b-7392-4755-9613-c4e2d53b61f3] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "freelancers" does not exist
2022-06-19T11:39:09.895116+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 9:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"freelancers"'::regclass
2022-06-19T11:39:09.895116+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-19T11:39:09.895117+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2022-06-19T11:39:09.895117+00:00 app[web.1]: [56ddbc7b-7392-4755-9613-c4e2d53b61f3]
2022-06-19T11:39:09.895118+00:00 app[web.1]: [56ddbc7b-7392-4755-9613-c4e2d53b61f3] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2022-06-19T11:39:09.895890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=freelancers-applc.herokuapp.com request_id=56ddbc7b-7392-4755-9613-c4e2d53b61f3 fwd="86.6.238.212" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2022-06-19T11:40:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user lc169782@protonmail.com
2022-06-19T11:41:27.499422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2022-06-19T11:41:27.512420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-06-19T11:41:28.234391+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-06-19T11:41:28.301459+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2022-06-19T11:41:28.302141+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2022-06-19T11:41:28.465197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-06-19T11:41:31.159791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2022-06-19T11:41:33.789631+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2022-06-19T11:41:33.789645+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.3 application starting in production
2022-06-19T11:41:33.789646+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2022-06-19T11:41:35.043903+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2022-06-19T11:41:35.043926+00:00 app[web.1]: * Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Birdie's Version")
2022-06-19T11:41:35.043927+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Min threads: 5
2022-06-19T11:41:35.043927+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Max threads: 5
2022-06-19T11:41:35.043927+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Environment: production
2022-06-19T11:41:35.043927+00:00 app[web.1]: *          PID: 4
2022-06-19T11:41:35.044142+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:40363
2022-06-19T11:41:35.049871+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2022-06-19T11:41:35.558521+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-06-19T11:41:36.896132+00:00 app[web.1]: [2d887a83-67fd-43af-a463-15307f715ab7] Started GET "/" for 86.6.238.212 at 2022-06-19 11:41:36 +0000
2022-06-19T11:41:36.897465+00:00 app[web.1]: [2d887a83-67fd-43af-a463-15307f715ab7] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2022-06-19T11:41:36.961014+00:00 app[web.1]: [2d887a83-67fd-43af-a463-15307f715ab7] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 63ms (ActiveRecord: 29.9ms | Allocations: 4701)
2022-06-19T11:41:36.963144+00:00 app[web.1]: [2d887a83-67fd-43af-a463-15307f715ab7]
2022-06-19T11:41:36.963146+00:00 app[web.1]: [2d887a83-67fd-43af-a463-15307f715ab7] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "freelancers" does not exist
2022-06-19T11:41:36.963148+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 9:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"freelancers"'::regclass
2022-06-19T11:41:36.963150+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-19T11:41:36.963151+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2022-06-19T11:41:36.963151+00:00 app[web.1]: [2d887a83-67fd-43af-a463-15307f715ab7]
2022-06-19T11:41:36.963151+00:00 app[web.1]: [2d887a83-67fd-43af-a463-15307f715ab7] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2022-06-19T11:41:36.964304+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=freelancers-applc.herokuapp.com request_id=2d887a83-67fd-43af-a463-15307f715ab7 fwd="86.6.238.212" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=74ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "freelancers" does not exist
> 2022-06-19T11:36:47.820512+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 9:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"freelancers"'::regclass

As you can see in the log table `freelancers` doesn't exist. You need to run the migration to make it work.

Run the migration through [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)
`heroku run rails db:migrate -a app-name`

Use Heroku Dashboard to run the migration

- I. Login to [Heroku](https://heroku.com/)
- II. Select the app > Click on `More` options
- III. Click on `Run Console`
- IV. Enter `rake db:migrate` and Click
  `Run`